# How do I list pod name/version across multiple clusters in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have multiple clusters that I want to query and in each cluster I want to find and list the versions of the pods running in there.

I've written a shell script that sets the namespace and then changes context to each cluster and then runs `kubectl describe pods | grep "/version=" -B1` in each cluster.

This seems to be a very hacky and clumsy approach to this problem. Is there a succinct command in the Kubernetes realm that I can issue that will take a list of clusters and return the name/version of each pod?

I feel that there are 2 problems described here and help with either or both would be appreciated:

1. How do I issue commands like `kubectl describe pods` to multiple clusters at the same time and aggregate those results?
2. What is best way to list names with versions of each pod in a cluster?

Update: I built an assumption into the questions that the answer would be a scripted `kubectl` command but it does not need to be. The objective is to find all the name/version combos of all pods running in listed clusters.

Answer (score 2):

The best I have found so far for part 2 is to use the JSON output of `get pods`:

```
kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.labels."app.kubernetes.io/name") | { name: .metadata.labels."app.kubernetes.io/name", version: .metadata.labels."app.kubernetes.io/version" }'
```

produces

```
{
  "name": "db",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: That's definitely a nicer result than I'm currently producing. It does require that anyone using the command have `jq` installed which I guess is a reasonable requirement. Conversely what I'm currently doing requires that everyone have `grep` installed.

Comment: I'd suggest using `-o jsonpath` or `-o custom-columns` to avoid external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For listing versions of each container in each pod I found that the [kubectl-images](https://github.com/chenjiandongx/kubectl-images) plugin is quite useful.